# React Native Changed Directory Name Packager not running anymore

Tags: ios, react-native

I changed the name for my directory from code to Code and when I run `react-native run-ios`, the simulator starts but the packager doesn't start anymore. What do I have to change to fix this without having to change my directory name back?

This is the error I am getting:

> error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '/Users/kelvin/Documents/Code/Tutorial/React-Native/manager/ios/build/ModuleCache/YT5URB46FE58', but the path is currently '/Users/kelvin/Documents/code/Tutorial/React-Native/manager/ios/build/ModuleCache/YT5URB46FE58'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing previous build folder and create it again.

```
rm -rf ios/build  // for removing
react-native run-ios  // create build and run
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache module `'/Users/kelvin/Documents/code/Tutorial/React-Native/manager/ios/build/ModuleCache'`